# How do I use Zip in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am very very new to clojure. The zip utility looks interesting but I cant seem to use it.

I tried

```
;; ZIP
(:use "zip")
(def data '[[a * b] + [c * d]])
(def dz (zip/vector-zip data))
```

But I am getting

```
java.lang.Exception: No such namespace: zip
```

How do yo use external libraries?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may be confusing two different ways to import code.  You can do it this way:

```
user> (use 'clojure.zip)
```

Or while you're declaring a namespace in a source file:

```
(ns foo
  (:use clojure.zip))
```

The second version is a macro that is expanded into the first.

Outside of `(ns)`, doing `(:use "zip")` is going to treat `:use` as a function and call it with `"zip"` as its parameter (i.e. try to use the string `"zip"` as a collection and look up the key `:use` in it), which does nothing.

`clojure.zip` has some functions whose names clash with things in `clojure.core` though, so you either have to do something like this:

```
user> (use '(clojure [zip :rename {next next-zip replace replace-zip remove remove-zip}]))
```

Or preferably this:

```
user> (require '(clojure [zip :as zip]))
```

With the latter you can refer to functions like `(zip/vector-zip data)` as you wish.

See the documentation for [require](http://clojure.org/api#require) and [refer](http://clojure.org/api#refer) and the page talking about [libs](http://clojure.org/libs).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer... I learned a few things from that. :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about clojure, but this little ditty seems to work:

```
(require '[clojure.zip :as zip]) 
(def t '(:a (:b :d) (:c :e :f))) 
(def z (zip/zipper rest rest cons t)) 
(zip/node z)
```